# How to get user details of Azure Notebook using extension?

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook, azure-active-directory, azure-notebooks, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I am trying to write an extension for the Azure notebook which will allow the user to submit their questions to my backend application(written in Flask).

So far my extension's javascript is able to get the .ipynb file details and cell number and send it to the backend application along with the user's question.

Now I want to send the user information also to the backend application so that I can associate the question to the respective user in my application's database.

I did a lot of google search but I am not able to find a proper way to get Azure notebook's user information in my extension's javascript and send it to the backend application.

Does anyone know what is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 0):

Yugendra. Based on my researching ,maybe you could call [Microsoft Graph NoteBooks REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/notebook?view=graph-rest-1.0) in your extension js to get the user information of notebooks.

I test [list notebook rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onenote-list-notebooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) in the https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and the `createdBy` property shows the user information.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Jay, I am busy with something else right now. I will try your solution in 2-3 days and let you know.